# Why is my view not updating when state changes in react/redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am having difficulty with my React/Redux application. I am trying to check whether a person has signed in by dispatching an action in componentDidMount. I have console logged in my application to see the control flow and it goes through response.ok and into the reducer where I log the action and state. Then my reducer returns a new state. However, the view is not updating properly as in my view the state.signedIn property is not updating properly displaying the button rather than the text that indicates a user has signed in.

This is my component:

```
class Attendance extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: props.user.email,
      name: props.user.name,
      id: props.user.id
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(checkSignIn(this.state.id));
  }


  render() {

    const page = this.state.signedIn ? (
        <div>
          Congratulations you have signed
        </div>
      ) : (
      <div>
        <button>Attendance</button>
      </div>
    );
    return page;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    token: state.auth.token,
    user: state.auth.user,
    signedIn: state.signedIn
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Attendance);
```

This is my action:

```
export function checkSignIn(id) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'CLEAR_MESSAGES'
    });
    return fetch('/checkAttendance', {
      method: "post",
      headers: {"Content-type":"application/json"},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        id: id
      })
    }).then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        console.log("response === ", response);
        return response.json().then((json) => {
          console.log("json === ", json);
          dispatch({
            type: "CHECK_ATTENDANCE_SUCCESS",
            message: json
          });
        });
      }else{
        console.log("response not okay");
        return response.json().then((json) => {
          dispatch({
            type: "CHECK_ATTENDANCE_FAILURE",
            message: json
          });
        });
      }
    })
  }
```

And this is my reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    signedIn: false,
}

export default function attendance(state = initialState, action){
    if (!state.hydrated) {
        state = Object.assign({}, initialState, state, { hydrated: true});
    }
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CHECK_ATTENDANCE_SUCCESS":
      console.log("check attendance success");
      console.log("state === ",state);
      console.log("action === ", action);
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        signedIn: action.message.signedIn
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should try renaming componentDidMount to componentWillMount

Comment: I don't think that should make a difference. ComponentWillMount is called immediately before initial rendering and ComponentDidMount is called after. Additionally the official docs say that ComponentDidMount is where ajax request should be performed. And I perform a fetch to the server.

Comment: Also I tried changing it and it still doesn't work

Comment: In your render(), you have `const page = this.state.signedIn`. Shouldnt this be `this.props.signedIn` ?

Comment: Where exactly? If you are talking about the view state holds the current state of the application. In redux we use state to store the data your current page needs in your controller-view and we use props to pass data & event handlers down to child components. So I don't see why we would use this.props.signedIn.

Comment: First line of your component's render method. mapStateToProps maps redux state to local props, not local state.

Comment: I see. I changed the first line to page = this.props.signedIn and it is still not working.

Comment: how state and combine reducers looks like. i assume that 'attendance' is not root reducer, then probably in mapStateToProps you should change `signedIn: state.signedIn` to `signedIn: state.attendance.signedIn`

Comment: AH! I put the attendance reducer in the combineReducers functoin but I forgot to reference it as state.attendance.signedIn in mapStateToProps as pointed out by Ultro. Additionally, I also had to use this.props.signedIn as jzm pointed out.